# Elastic search - Scroll id - How to get current page result again ?

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination

Hi We are using elastic search scroll concept to get large data in index . We are getting scrollid and hitting scrollid to get the data sequentially .

Let asssume totally I have 100 page . In 90th request due to some network issue or timeout I am not getting 90th page result . If I hit again scroll id I will get 91 th page . 90th page result is missing.

To over some this issue I have to request for new scrollid , I need to start from page 1 again .

Is there any way to solve this issue . **How can I get current page without forwarding it to next page ?**

Is it possible? If not is there any workaround for this .

Thanks in advance.